# Modify label text on click in listview

Tags: listview, xamarin, viewmodel, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged

This is my code:

```
 public partial class MyGS: ContentPage {
   private GestioneSchedeViewModel _viewModel;
   
   public MyGS() {
     InitializeComponent();
     BindingContext = _viewModel  = new MyGSViewModel();
   }

  private void modifySch(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
     SchedeItem item = (SchedeItem)((Image)sender).BindingContext;
     if (item == null) { return; }
     _viewModel.modifyItem(item.realm_id, item.list_id);
   }
  }

  public class MyGSViewModel: INotifyCollectionChanged {
   public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;

   public ObservableCollection < SchItem > Items {get;private set;}

   public MyGSViewModel() {
    Items = new ObservableCollection<SchItem>();
    //Item Population 
   }

   public void modificaItem(int rid, int lid)
    {
      SchedeItem myItem = Items[lid];
      myItem.name = "New Text";
    }

   protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
      PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

   }

   public class SchItem : INotifyPropertyChanged {
     public int realm_id {get;set;}
     public int list_id {get;set;}
     public int name {get;set;}

     public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

     protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
   }

}
```

How can I change the label text binded with name in the listview on image click ? At the moment, on click doesn't change and "New Text" isn't showed in target item in listview.

> Note: XAML [here](http://pastebin.com/TSBri1Jj)
>
> Note: Debugging in Android Device

Comment: if you are modifying a property of SchItem, then that class needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: doesn't work implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` in SchItem class

Comment: are you implementing it correctly?

Comment: @Jason i've updated question, let me know

Comment: @Segamoto nop, not correctly ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to execute the OnPropertyChanged() method in the setter for each property, in order to notify the bindings and 'refresh' the text.

```
    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            if (name == value)
            {
                return;
            }
            name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

Don't forget to update the Binding path in order to use the property and not the private field... ({Binding Name})